# How to test for time of day with command block in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to setup something similar to the MindCrack team's current server set up for my single player world so that the world border expands slowly as I play the game. I already know how to work the worldborder command, I just want it to happen at the exact same time every game day.

I know that you can query for the time with `time query daytime` which gives you the time of the day in ticks. I would set up a comparator to test the output. I just can't seem to get the `testfor` command to work with this. I figure I'm doing something wrong. I would guess the code would be something like this `testfor [time query daytime = 1000]` but of course that was wrong.

Anyone know if what I want to do is even possible?

Comment: If you want to have an expanding border, then why don't you just ask how to get it? I can't answer this question, but I can tell you how to get an expanding border. Please change your question if possible.

Comment: Welp, had to make another [question](http://arqade.com/q/181937) to make my [answer](http://arqade.com/a/181938) appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're along the right path with `/time query daytime`.

First of all, create an objective. In these examples I'll use "TimeObjective" although you can call it whatever you want:

```
/scoreboard objectives add TimeObjective dummy
```

Next, put `/time query daytime` into a command block. Then stand ontop of the command block and type this. Again, "TimePlayer" is just a fake player name, it can be anything so long as it's consistent:

```
/stats block ~ ~-1 ~ set QueryResult TimePlayer TimeObjective
```

Now, whenever the command block is activated, the current time will be stored in TimePlayer's TimeObjective score. Set that block on a clock. To test the score of a player that doesn't actually exist, you need to use this command rather than /testfor:

```
/scoreboard players test <PLAYER> <OBJECTIVE> <MIN> <MAX>
```

So for this case:

```
/scoreboard players test TimePlayer TimeObjective 0 1000
```

Comment: Awesome works except you forgot one command, that I had to look up. `/scoreboard players add TimePlayer TimeObjective 0` then the command block produced the right output. Thanks for your help works exactly like I wanted.

Comment: Well it would work perfectly if the time query returned correctly. It seems as of now using MC 1.8-pre1 is that unless you issue a command `/time set day` or such then the time continues the count and doesn't start over from 0 as it is shown in the wiki. I think I'm probably going to check with Mojang's bug tracker and see if this is an open issue.

Comment: Mojang confirmed it is a bug. A modolo 24000 is missing.

Comment: Just to inform everyone who reads this. The bug I've mentioned in the comment above has been corrected and everything is working correctly as of Minecraft 1.9

Answer (score 2):

The following steps apply to the **1.13.1** version of Minecraft:

1. Create a dummy scoreboard. Type the following command into chat;

   ***/scoreboard objectives add timeOfDay dummy "Time of Day (in ticks)"***
2. Show the scoreboard for testing. Use the command below;

   ***/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar timeOfDay***
3. Summon an Armor Stand and name it "timeOfDay". You could use this command;

   ***/summon armor_stand ~ ~1 ~ {NoGravity:1,CustomName:"{\"text\":\"timeOfDayArmorStand\"}",CustomNameVisible:1b}***
4. Set the value of the time of day (in ticks) as the timeOfDay scoreboard value 
   for the timeOfDayArmorStand. Paste the command in an active repeating command block;

   ***/execute store result score @e[type=armor_stand,name=timeOfDayArmorStand] timeOfDay run time query daytime***

   To remove the timeOfDay scoreboard in the right side of the screen, type this;

   ***/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar***

Comment: You can also store the value under a "fake name" instead of using an armor stand: `/execute store result score FakePlayer timeOfDay run time query daytime` (and skip the summon step)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out for what I was doing it was easy I just put a comparator up next to a command block with this command in it:

/time query daytime

Then I had two pieces of redstone going from that comparator to a block with a torch on it going to a command block.

Comment: This doesnt actually answer the question. And it doesn't even look like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested in this, a way you can get around the bug where the time doesn't reset to zero, is test for if the time query is 24000, like with:

```
/scoreboard players test timeFakePlayer time 23990 24000
```

Then have the comparator set the time to 0 with `/time set 0` since that time of day is equal to zero